# Twitter search API suddenly stopped returning results

Tags: php, twitter

I've been using the Twitter search api and PHP to pull in tweets from my account:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from=myaccount

(using simplexml and caching the feed so I'm only calling to twitter once and hour)

It's been working fine for about two weeks, now nothing. When I visit the url above (with my account ) I don't get anything apart from the title of the feed.

The response I get in the headers is:

```
Date    Wed, 27 Jul 2011 20:16:55 GMT
Server  hi
Status  200 OK
X-Served-From   smf1-aek-11-sr2
X-Runtime   0.13606
Content-Type    application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
X-Timeline-Cache-Hit    Miss
X-Served-By smf1-aas-19-sr2.prod.twitter.com
Cache-Control   max-age=15, must-revalidate, max-age=1800
Expires Wed, 27 Jul 2011 20:46:55 GMT
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish   1602110106
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
X-Cache-Svr smf1-aas-19-sr2.prod.twitter.com
X-Cache MISS
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  413
Connection  close
X-Moz-Is-Feed   1
```

...I think this is all good. I've not been rate limited then apparently I'd get a 400 error...but this looks all good to me. I just can't figure out why this would have stopped working. Nothing has changed.

I did look at the headers from another twitter page which is returning me tweets in xml and the headers are almost indentical - apart from the status line is missing:

```
Date    Wed, 27 Jul 2011 20:24:42 GMT
Server  hi
Cache-Control   max-age=15, must-revalidate, max-age=300
Expires Wed, 27 Jul 2011 20:29:42 GMT
Content-Type    application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
X-Pad   avoid browser bug
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish   1922281127  
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
X-Cache-Svr smf1-aap-11-sr1.prod.twitter.com
X-Cache MISS
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  1919
 Connection close
X-Moz-Is-Feed   1
```

Any ideas? Has anyone else encountered this problem? I can provide more info about the reponse if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search api only returns results for the last 4-6 days.. I know useless.

I haven't found a work around for this either

Comment: Ah ok, Well I can't tell if any of the posts are older than that...I didn't make them and there seems to be no way to see dates of tweets on twitter (not a user of Twitter myself)....is that right? You can't see tha date of a tweet?!

Comment: um I can't remember, I would assume they have a date stamp... but then again the search results are only for 4-6 days. When it happened to me i knew when the tweets were tweeted so then figured it out by doing a little research on google.

Comment: Yes! This was the problem! Someone has just tweeted this morning and it's now showing in my feed. Thanks for your time :)